# iOS Twitter api deleting favorites gives error code: 34

Tags: twitter, error-handling, ios7, slrequest

I have an application that lets you view your favorited tweets, and it also lets you remove them from favorites if you don't want it anymore.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error:

```
2013-10-13 17:33:57.306 MyApp[6233:a0b] {
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 34;
            message = "Sorry, that page does not exist";
        }
    );
}
```

Here is my code that is calling the request:

```
#define TW_API_DESTROY_FAVORITE @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/destroy.json"




- (void)deleteFavoriteWithID:(NSString *)tweetID atIndex:(int) index {


    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:TW_API_DESTROY_FAVORITE];

    // Get AppDelegate reference
    AppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSMutableDictionary *favoriteParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [favoriteParameters setObject:tweetID forKey:@"id"];


    // Create TWRequest, with parameters, URL & specify GET method
    SLRequest *twitterFeed = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:theURL parameters:favoriteParameters];

    // Specify twitter request's account to our app delegate's
    twitterFeed.account = appDelegate.userAccount;


    // Making the request

    [twitterFeed performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Check if we reached the reate limit

            if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");

                return;
            }

            // Check if there was an error

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }

            // Check if there is some response data

            if (responseData) {

                NSError *jsonError = nil;
                id feedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];
                if (!jsonError) {

                    NSLog(@"%@", feedData);




                } else {

                    // Alert the user of an error


                    });

                }


            }



        });

    }];

}
```

For whatever reason it is just NOT accepting this. Elsewhere in the app, I am using the EXACT same code and it works fine, but for whatever reason this will not fire properly.

Any ideas? Thanks!